# How to make python discord bot use a command every minute

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my python discord bot to use a command every minute.

Currently I have set it up like this:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def mytask():
    channel = bot.get_channel(305347032569348107)
    await channel.send('Example message')
```

and `mytask.start()` in `async def on_ready()` function

It works fine and sends example message but I want it to actually execute a command, for example, I may have another bot which has a !coin command for the coin toss and I want my bot to use this command every minute.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Or maybe perhaps I already that? I know about the seconds and minutes in the decorator, however, the sending/executing of commands still doesn't work `await channel.send(!coin) SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I also tried with `await channel.send('!coin')`

Comment: It's likely that the bot you're trying to run commands to have a mechanism to ignore commands sent by bots.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop) it allows for seconds, minutes, or hours:

```
discord.ext.tasks.loop(*, seconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, count=None, reconnect=True, loop=None)
```

So your decorator now becomes:

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
```

Comment: I know about the seconds, I used 10 seconds just to test it however the issue with sending/executing commands still exist.

I tried `channel.send(!coin)` also `channel.send("!coin") both do not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def mytask():
    channel = bot.get_channel(305347032569348107)
    await channel.send(!coin)
```

:s

Comment: doesn't work `await channel.send(!coin) SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I also tried `await channel.send("!coin")` but that just sends the message.